# What exactly is an off topic question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, off-topic

I've seen the moderators define specific questions as "off topic" on Stack Overflow. Nevertheless, I haven't been able to find the proper definition of "off topic." Is it a type of question that is not related to code or has an opinion?

Comment: [What is On-Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [what shouldn't I ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I was thinking something that related directly to programming....

Comment: There are many programming-related questions that are off-topic for StackOverflow. If the linked documentation doesn't answer your question, consider linking to your question so that we can provide specific details about why it was considered off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An off topic question is simply a question that doesn't fit within the scope of the site. So if your question isn't:

> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - [about] tools commonly used by programmers
> - [a] practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession

...then it is off topic.

---

For the definition of what is on-topic you should check the specific site's Help Center.

For Stack Overflow see:

- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: How do we mark a question as off topic, or vote for it to be closed? Is a down vote for the question the same thing?

Comment: Declaring a question off-topic is too simple and abusive. When a question is declared off-topic, the user must be advise about the reason (why this question is off-topic) and also about the alternative (in which other Q&A site this question must be posted). Declaring a question off-topic without this 2 explanations is a stupid thing !

Comment: @schlebe If the user has posted an off-topic question, they have already clicked an acknowledgement that they read the description of what is on-topic. How many times should they be presented with the same link that they are ignoring before it is not considered abusive to simply close the question?

Comment: @schlebe, when a question is closed, a box is generated at the top of the question explaining why the question was closed, and it has a link to the proper help topic for the reason, e.g. "_We don’t allow questions about general computing hardware and software on Stack Overflow. You can edit the question so it’s [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow._" What more needs to be supplied?